# Flutter: why my app started throwing exception?

Tags: flutter, exception, video-player

**Hello**
I am working with the **VideoPlayer** plugin, everything is working good till before but now it started throwing this exception.
 ** _AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/services/message_codec.dart': Failed assertion: line 111 pos 15: '***code != null***': is not true.) ** More Detail: [image: error 01] [image: error 02][image: error 03] Log:[image] 
The video player initializing code is as follows:

```html
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      _videoController =VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/videos/video_1.mp4")
      ..initialize().then((value) {
       _videoController.play();
        setState(() {
          
          isShowPlaying = false;
        });
      });

      
  }
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The picture you shared does not show the line where the error is spotted!
`Failed assertion: line 111 pos 15: 'code != null': is not true.)`

Comment: you mean this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHaID.png ?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about this picture.

Comment: I noticed one thing, it is throwing exception on assets, it's working fine with network url/videos.

Comment: If you share the code, the exception is pointing to, I might be able to help. `Failed assertion: line 111 pos 15: 'code != null': is not true.`

Comment: sorry for the late response, I have added some more detail, let me know if this can help

Comment: Have you followed this tutorial by flutter.dev? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video

Comment: yes, I did, hopefully I didn't missed anything. I wonder that everything was working perfect but then suddenly that day when I debug my project in the morning it shows error and when I change asset to network url everything is fine again.

Comment: I'm unable to see any issue with this code. I'll try it my self to see if there is an issue with the plugin.

Comment: Yes please, let me know if you find some solution. Thank you

Comment: @kiran I got the same problem with network and asset video. I updated VideoPlayer lib to ^0.11.1+2 and implemented VideoWidget once again with https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video instruction. The error seems to be gone. Please check once again link above cuz initialization of video player changed. E.g. they are using FutureBuilder widget.

Comment: Sure, I will check it out. Thanks

Comment: @DaArtagnan is right, I was able to reproduce the exception by means of `initialization` of the controller. By using the newer method to initialize the controller provided here flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video , there are no exceptions but the Asset video is not appearing on the UI. 
I tried their example and it does not run the asset video either. You can try it out yourself.
Example: https://pub.dev/packages/video_player/example

Comment: Yes, I have code everything again as said by @DaArtagnan but still not able to make it work with asset videos.